# Power Query Editor with Kusto Query Lanugage

Tags: powerquery, azure-data-explorer

Can get a hand with passing in a parameter from a power editor function to power editor query?

Here's a portion of my query:

```
let
    Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("mycluster", "mydatabse", "let startTime = datetime(2021-02-26 00:00:00); #(lf)let interval = timespan(24h);
```

I want to replace the 24h with a query editor parameter or query editor function.  But when I do so, I get syntax errors as power editor complains that timespan is not formatted correctly.  I don't know what/how to format the insertion of a function call OR parameter in the code above.

For what it's worth, the query above is a Kusto (i.e. azure data explorer) query.  I have tried

timespan([myparam])
timespan([{myparam]})
timespan({myparam})
timespan([myfunction() )

Nothing works. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm gong to assume that your parameter is of type Number, which represents the number of hours you'd like to set for the "interval" variable. The easiest to handle that is to use string concating:

```
Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("mycluster", "mydatabse", "let startTime = datetime(2021-02-26 00:00:00); #(lf)let interval = timespan(" & MyIntervalParameter & "h);")
```

Another alternative is to use M's Text.Format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-format) function:

```
Query = Text.Format(
    "let startTime = datetime(2021-02-26 00:00:00); #(lf)let interval = timespan(#[interval]h);",
    [
        interval = MyIntervalParameter
    ]),
Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("mycluster", "mydatabse", Query)
```

Comment: Interesting format.  I'm going to try that now.  BTW, I intentionally set the types to (a) String then (b) Any.  But I see the funky formatting you've done above.  Will try that now.  Thanks a ton.  Hope this works.  I'll reply shortly with my findings